# The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-5.0

I have made a change to Identity to add a custom field. Following a tutorial it mentioned that I needed to inject

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <form  class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
            <button  type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
        </form>
    </li>
}
else
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

The ApplicationUser file (see below) exists and changes have been made to all references to IdentityUser within the project. For some reason, it does not want to recognise the file within my login partial file.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace WebApp1.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something as I feel like I have done everything right?  I'm at a loss and tried a few things I found via google but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I added the @using WebApp1.Data line to the top of the partial file which worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).